# Javascript regular expression to not allow space in a textfield

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a text field which takes emails, more than one email is separated by comma, so I want a regular expression which will not allow space in that text field i.e the space bar will not work. pls help..
Thanks.

Comment: You can use this `/\s/` regular expression to match whitespace characters (space, tab, line endings)

Comment: I want the space bar will not work i.e one can not insert space in that field. I want add that regular expression in maskRe property of textfield in extjs.

Comment: `maskRe: /[^\s]/` are you searching for this?..

Comment: Note that `\s` matches quite a bit more than a space character - it matches all whitespace characters: `\f\n\r\t\v\u00A0\u2028\u2029 ` . (Also note that you can use `\S` instead of `[^\s]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
maskRe: /[^ ]/
```

`[^ ]` means anything except the space character. If you wanted to match all whitespace and not just the space character, use `/\S/`

Answer (score 1):

Don't break the expected user input model. Clean up the input after submission (split on comma then trim each part). Breaking the spacebar will just annoy people.